# Post an NSString with spaces to an online form

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSString * myName = @"Sjakelien Vleeschbaardt";      
NSString *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myhost.nl/createUser.php?name=%@", myName];
NSString *url =[urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

With the URL, I store myName in an online mySQL database.
I understand, that a URL shouldn't contain spaces, and that these spaces should be escaped. As a result of above code, myName ends up in the database, encapsulated with 'single quotes'.

The question is, where/when should I compensate for this problem?

1. In the code above? Maybe I should use a different encoding?
2. Server side? Can mySQL or PHP fix this before storing?
3. Upon retrieving the data, by bluntly removing the quotes? And what if somebody's name is O'Hara?

**UPDATE: MY BAD**

I'm awfully sorry.

I discovered that what I simplified in my example as "NSString * myName=" in my real code is represented by *something that introduces the single quotes*.

I hope somebody makes the same mistake, and can find some comfort here.

Comment: Such as it may help others to answer: confirmed that the above produces the URL `http://www.myhost.nl/createUser.php?name=Sjakelien%20Vleeschbaardt`.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, you made me re-check my code.